# How to scroll a DevExpress Xtragrid horizontally but by full columns

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I want to scroll a grid horizontally. By default, it scrolls pixel by pixel. I want to scroll column by column. Simply, a column should shift to left/right 100% or 0%. Shouldn't scroll by a fraction of it's width. (This applies to the first column visible to the user at the moment).

What I want is a way to do "snappy" scroll.

How can I get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scroll grid's content, use the [GridView.LeftCoord](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.LeftCoord.property) property. To access boundaries of columns, the **GridViewInfo.ColumnsInfo** collection will be helpful. You can see how to implement this feature in the [How to implement scrolling by columns in the grid e2481](https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/how-to-implement-scrolling-by-columns-in-the-grid-e2481) example.

Comment: Thank you. Only trouble I have with this is that the scrollbar behavior is funny.